# C fwrite() writes amount of characters doubled

Tags: c, char, fwrite

When I use this code

```
FILE *f = fopen(file, "wb");
fflush(f);
if (f==NULL) {
    //perror(f);
    return 0;
}
else{
    fwrite(text, sizeof(char), strlen(text), f);
    int i = fprintf(f, "%s", text);
    if (i>0) {
        fclose(f);

        return  1;
    }
```

(`text` is `const char text[1024000]`, which is set as one of the arguments in the function)
if I write

```
This is a test
This is a test
```

to test if it can write multiple lines, it writes this

```
This is a test
This is a testThis is a test
This is a test
```

why do I get this weird behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're writing twice:

```
fwrite(text, sizeof(char), strlen(text), f);
int i = fprintf(f, "%s", text);
```

Pick one

Answer (score 0):

These two lines write "text" twice. They do same thing.

```
fwrite(text, sizeof(char), strlen(text), f);
int i = fprintf(f, "%s", text);
```

The only difference is fprintf write one more byte '\0' than fwrite.

Comment: Ha, beat you by 12 seconds ;)